# problems with the OnAdPaid event ADMOB

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob-rewardedvideoad

hello and sorry for my bad english i'am native french speaker, i have a problem with admob, the OnAdPaid event is never called when i use real ads, but works perfectly with test ads.

I would like to give a reward to a player when the advert passes the reward mark i.e. 15-30 seconds.

I would have put a timer of 30 sec but the reward cap on adMob scale between 15 and 30 sec